# How to initially install a Winforms App to use AutoUpdater.Net

Tags: installation, clickonce

I have a .Net Winforms application which I wish to move away from Clickonce as the installer/updater and have chosen to use AutoUpdater.Net (https://github.com/ravibpatel/AutoUpdater.NET)

However the documentation only shows how to update the app, how do you get users to initially install the application on their PC ?

Expecting users to perhaps have a simple install URL or file location they can simply run to install it in the first instance.